# Assign class variables with a loop in groovy

Tags: loops, variables, groovy, variable-assignment

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to accomplish what I am looking for.  Let's say I have 5 different String variables:
String string1 = "A"

String string2 = "B"

String string3 = "A"

String string4 = "B"

String string5 = "A"

What I want to do is loop over those 5 variables and if they equal B, I want to set them to A.  What I have tried is something like:

```
[string1,string2,string3,string4,string5].each {
     if (it == "B"){
        //don't know what to put here
        need to set variable = "A" here
     }
}
```

I don't know how to get the actual variable name in the closure for the assignment.  Maybe I am not searching correctly for what I am trying to do, but I need to be able to set strin2 and string4 to "A" with this loop.

I know I can do 5 if statements, but I know there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Do you want to change the object that variables like `string1` point to, or do you want to leave that reference as it is and just put a new value in the List in place of the old one (which would not have any impact on the `string1` reference)?

Comment: I want to change what it points to, from A to B.  I don't care what the original value was.

Comment: @jcattau, it depends how you declared those string1-string5. if those are the members/properties of some object/map/script - then `obj['string1'] = "B"` will do the assignment. if they are the local variables - then no chance.

Answer (score 1):

you can set an object (class) member with `obj[property] = value` if it's a groovy object or map

for example

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class X {
    String string1 = "A"
    String string2 = "B"
    String string3 = "A"
    String string4 = "B"
    String string5 = "A"

    void switchAll(vOld,vNew){
        this.getProperties().each{k,v->
            if(k ==~ /string\d+/ && v==vOld) this[k] = vNew
        }
     }
     
}

def x = new X()
println x

x.switchAll("B","C")
println x
```

prints:

```
X(A, B, A, B, A)
X(A, C, A, C, A)
```

Comment: I'm going to see if I can work with this, but the strings1 through 5 may not always be "A" or "B", so I want to loop through them and check if they are "A" and if so change to "B".  But these are local variables I was trying to work with.

Comment: there is a condition in my answer `if( ... v==vOld)`. and you mentioned in your question that it's a class variables. with local variables - nothing will work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know enough about development for automated testing but still struggle with some concepts.  They are class variables declared in the class, not local variables.  I mixed up the concept.